# offscreen parallax node scrolling with cclayers

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, nodes, parallax

Mange to scroll my CCLayers with parallax node but how do I set the bounds of the scroll?

Using:

```
- (void)registerWithTouchDispatcher {
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:1 swallowsTouches:NO];
}

-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}

-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];   
    CGPoint prevLocation = [touch previousLocationInView: [touch view]];    

    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: touchLocation];
    prevLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: prevLocation];

    CGPoint diff = ccpSub(touchLocation,prevLocation);

    CCNode *node = [self getChildByTag:kTagNode];
    CGPoint currentPos = [node position];
    [node setPosition: ccpAdd(currentPos, diff)];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the swallowsTouches property of the ZoomController and look at the TargetTouchDelegate to handle more complicated touch events.

Comment: But how I can have them in the same time? My Parallax images are larger and if scrolling all the way to the right I have a sprite which is backward and can't reach to it...